# early warning for HDD issues

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk, monitoring

I am using Linux Mint 20.

```
% inxi -S
System:    Host: ismail-i5 Kernel: 5.4.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana
```

I have 3 HDD and 1 SSD.

```
% lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 232.4G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   3.7T  0 part /media/ismail/WDPurple
sdc      8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0   3.7T  0 part /media/ismail/WDRed
sdd      8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sdd1   8:49   0   3.7T  0 part /media/ismail/Toshiba
```

I want to have an early warning if any of my storage devices fail.

I know I can use the following to check my HDD health.

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX
```

And if I see that `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` or `Current_Pending_Sector` has value anything other than 0 then I should be concern and take necessary steps.

However, I do not want to always run this command and check the output. Is there any solution which I can use to have a warning when my storage devices start having problems.

Comment: `man smartctl` and then `nan smartd` to read up on the monitoring option. The built-in supplied documentation is usually a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any solution which I can use to have a warning when my storage devices start having problems.

There are two types of people in the world: those who make backups, and those who haven't started making backups.

Jokes aside, HDDs often die abruptly due to mechanical failures with **no** advance warnings or info but in a majority of cases information still can be retrieved. SSDs on the other hand most often die such a way information extraction is impossible.

Speaking of Reallocated Sectors Count: positive values do **not** necessarily indicate your storage is dying. SSDs **often** have them and continue to function for years. A more important metric is whether and how fast this parameter is growing. You may have a few reallocated sectors and enjoy a very long drive life span.

Current Pending Sector holds a single value and it's pretty much useless to make any estimates.

I personally run `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` every few months but this test is not without its **major** pitfalls. Imagine you have an impending mechanical failure and you continue recklessly performing this test. Now the failing recording heads may start physically scratching the surface of your platters and actually destroying the remaining information which could have been salvaged if you hadn't started the test.

To get notifications about your drives statuses make sure you've got `smartd.service` enabled.

I have it running with these options:

```
/usr/sbin/smartd -n -q never -s /var/lib/smartmontools
```

It uses `mail` to notify you about changes in your drives statuses.